# facebook ios sdk 2.0 stopped working 9/7/2012?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

We are using ios sdk 2.0 with an oauth dialog.  Everything seemed to be working fine until last few hours.

The dialog comes up and prompts for facebook uname/pword, upon submission the returned page says.... "The page you requested was not found" the "Back to previous page" link does nothing most of the time, although a few times we got an error code 100.

the app asks for publish_stream and email permissions.

Is the sdk 2.0 deprecated completely?

Also, we have been posting through the app a bit and sometimes deleting the posts or the app.  How can we find out facebook is filtering our app?

Comment: We have the same issue, have you found anything regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Facebook app's settings, click "Advanced" then select the "Desktop/Native" radio button in the "Authentication" section.